# How to get id of a subfield without query

Tags: database, graphql

How can I get the ID of the subfield without querying the element in the database.

My current approach is querying the subfield project,

```
 query GetUser($id: ID!) {
    getUser(id: $id){
      id
      project{
        id
      }
    }
  }
```

I need a solution like:

```
  query GetUser($id: ID!) {
    getUser(id: $id){
      id
      project
    }
  }
```

So I don't have to query the subfield.

Comment: if a prop has subfields then it can't be queried without them (will raise an error in playground editor) - what type it (`project`) should be? what value ?

Comment: You can always set up `getUser`'s `project` resolver so it doesn't load the whole project ahead of time. You could leave the `project { id }` as-is and wait until a property other than `id` is accessed to query the other properties. How are you writing your resolver functions?

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you have logic right now that some something along the lines of

```js
function resolveProject(user, args, context) {
  return loadProject(user.project_id);
}
```

which is why you are asking. The query does need to be

```
project {
  id
}
```

so you can't change it, but you could change your query function to lazy-load the project only once properties other than `id` are used, e.g.

```js
function resolveProject(user, args, context) {
  let promise;
  function getProject() {
    // you can always skip the caching logic if `loadProject` 
    // uses a DataLoader or something like it.
    if (!promise) {
      promise = loadProject(user.project_id);
    }
    return promise;
  }

  return {
    id: user.project_id,
    someProp: async () => (await getProject()).someProp,
    otherProp: async () => (await getProject()).otherProp,
  };
}
```

With a resolver like this,

```
project {
  id
}
```

is the same as accessing `user.project_id` and doesn't query the database for the project itself.